# Установить Telegram Bot API на linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, telegram-bot

У нас [инструкция](https://tdlib.github.io/telegram-bot-api/build.html?os=Linux). Однако отработав установку файлов программа CMake не может приступить к компиляции после отработки этой команды:

`$ CXXFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++" CC=/usr/bin/clang-10 CXX=/usr/bin/clang++-10 cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=.. ..`

В результате программа остаётся неустановленной. Исполнялось всё на Ubuntu 20.

Answer (score 0):

Перепробовав множество различных операций нашёл выход из положения. Надо запускать данные операции под правами администратора:

`sudo git clone --recursive https://github.com/tdlib/telegram-bot-api.git`

`sudo rm -rf build`

`sudo mkdir build`

`sudo CXXFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++" CC=/usr/bin/clang-10 CXX=/usr/bin/clang++-10 cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=.. ..`

`sudo cmake --build . --target install`

По крайней мере компиляция сейчас идёт.